# pgfmathparse does not correctly parse zero left-padded integers?

Tags: pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I am currently trying to realize a slightly complicated graphic, wherein I have a bunch files all named with the value of a certain parameter, represented by its left-padded value. Namely, I have:

> my_file_055.txt (param = 0.55)
>
> my_file_105.txt (param = 1.05)
>
> my_file_155.txt (param = 1.55)

So I set to generate a loop over `{055, 105, 155}`, and thought that using 

`\pgfmathparse{#1/100}\pgfmathresult`

Would give me the correct result. This works for `105` and `155` (Rounding issues aside), but gives me the incorrect value of `0.45` for `055`. This does appear with other zero-padded values, such as `035` that gives me `0.29`.

M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) node {\pgfmathparse{055/100}\pgfmathresult};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to get the correct value `0.35` out ?

Comment: Extract from pgf manual (section 89.1.1 "Commands", p.923, pgfmanual v3.0.1a): "_An integer with a zero-prefix (excluding, of course zero itself), is interpreted as an octal number
and is automatically converted to base 10._"

Comment: ...nice how we propagate one of the worst design decision in the hystory of software... ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extract from pgf manual (section 89.1.1 "Commands", p.923, pgfmanual v3.0.1a): "*An integer with a zero-prefix (excluding, of course zero itself), is interpreted as an octal number and is automatically converted to base 10.*"

So, with pgfmath, you can't use decimal numbers with zero-prefix!

Comment: Thanks for providing the correct explanation, however it is possible to convert zero-prefixed integers into regular integers, see my answer.

Comment: @Urukann Yes, you are right. I should have written "with `\pgfmathparse`, you can't use decimal numbers with zero-prefix".

Answer (score 8):

The LaTeX3 FPU can be used here and doesn't need the intermediate value step

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) node {\fpeval{059/100}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hum I'd rather not pull in more packages, but this does work!

Answer (score 5):

A solution is to forcefully interpret the number as a base 10 number. The following code makes use of `\pgfmathdectobase` to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfmathdectobase\mynumber{055}{10}
      \draw (0, 0) node {\pgfmathparse{\mynumber/100}\pgfmathresult};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For more information, see section 71.2.7 of the pgf manual, "Base conversion functions".